# Trying to use BufferedInputStream and Base64 to Encode a large file in Java

Tags: java, base64, apache-commons, bufferedinputstream

I am new to the Java I/O so please help.

I am trying to process a large file(e.g. a pdf file of 50mb) using the apache commons library.
At first I try:

```
byte[] bytes = FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(file);
String encodeBase64String = Base64.encodeBase64String(bytes);
byte[] decoded = Base64.decodeBase64(encodeBase64String);
```

But knowing that the
FileUtils.readFileToByteArray in `org.apache.commons.io` will load the whole file into memory, I try to use `BufferedInputStream` to read the file piece by piece:

```
BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(inputStream);
StringBuilder pdfStringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
int byteArraySize = 10;
byte[] tempByteArray = new byte[byteArraySize];
while (bis.available() > 0) {
                if (bis.available() < byteArraySize) { // reaching the end of file
                    tempByteArray = new byte[bis.available()];
                }
                int len = Math.min(bis.available(), byteArraySize);
                read = bis.read(tempByteArray, 0, len);

                if (read != -1) {
                    pdfStringBuilder.append(Base64.encodeBase64String(tempByteArray));
                } else {
                    System.err.println("End of file reached.");
                }
            }
byte[] bytes = Base64.decodeBase64(pdfStringBuilder.toString());
```

However, the 2 decoded bytes array don't look quite the same... ... In fact, the only give 10 bytes, which is my temp array size... ...

Can anyone please help:

- what am I doing it wrong to read the file piece by piece?
- why is the decoded byte array only returns 10 bytes in the 2nd solution?

Thanks in advance:)

Comment: Frankly, I would encourage you to try to encode the entire file at once: 50MB isn't really that large; Java's maximum string length is 2GB.

Comment: @paulsm4 Thanks for your suggestion:)

Comment: It is never correct to use InputStream.available() to check for the end of a stream.  Instead, check whether the `read` method returned a negative value.  See [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/io/InputStream.html#available()) for details.

Comment: @VGR: Thanks for your advice:) As a side question, is there any suggestion on how to remove/trim the NULs at the end of the last byte array?

Comment: There are certainly ways to process only part of a byte array, but I would first ask why you are base64 encoding data and then immediately bse64 decoding that same data.  You are correct that loading the entire file into memory into memory is a bad idea, but you are ultimately doing that anyway (twice!), since you still use a `bytes` variable.  What processing of the file do you actually want to do?

Answer (score 0):

After some digging, it turns out that the byte array's size has to be multiple of 3 in order to avoid padding. After using a temp array size with multiple of 3, the program is able to go through.

I simply change

```
int byteArraySize = 10;
```

to be

```
int byteArraySize = 1024 * 3;
```